# What is use of naming an image in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In a docker file what are the uses of naming an image like so...

`FROM <image> [AS <name>]`

One of uses I found from the docs is -

```
 - Optionally a name can be given to a new build stage by adding 
AS name to the FROM instruction. The name can be used in subsequent
FROM and COPY --from=<name|index> instructions to refer to the image 
built in this stage.
```

Are there any other uses?

One example here which is straight forward - https://medium.com/thepeaklab/how-to-deploy-a-react-application-to-production-with-docker-multi-stage-builds-4da347f2d681

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name/alias is just a way to refer to a specific stage in another stage. So if you are using the normal build no need to use it. Otherwise you will be using the index number for example:

```
FROM <image_image>
RUN <do_something>
...

FROM <image_name>
COPY --from=0 <files_to_copy> <destination>
...
```

The name also can be used in conjunction with `--target` [option to the build command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specifying-target-build-stage---target) for example:

```
FROM debian AS build-env
...

FROM alpine AS production-env
...
```

```
$ docker build -t mybuildimage --target build-env .
```